# My Solara 2005 showing hot steam coming under hood

Tags: engine, coolant, radiator

I have been smelling something strange over a week and now catch it

https://youtu.be/0tv9vBT_oKU

It is shooting hot steam and I believe one time I saw a little bit red fire coming out from the right side below the windshield

Is it just radiator problem? Or something more serious that was causing a small fire at one point

Comment: Is that a Talbot solara? Also Chrysler?

Comment: That is most certainly a Toyota Solara.